# How to read .txt file from the internet wirelessly

Tags: wifi, wireless, system-design

I am a *complete beginner* to Arduino, so I'm asking this moreso to see if a project will be feasible.

My ultimate goal is to have this arduino (whenever powered) check this website "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/aurora-nowcast-map.txt" (every 15 minutes or something). If a specific value in the sort of array of space delimited numbers is above a threshold, it'll turn on an LED.

**I want to use some WiFi shield (price is not an issue, I just don't want complicated powering) to have the Arduino read a .txt file from the internet. What will the simplest, most reliable hardware be, and how will I read this data in? An example may be very helpful!!!**

I think I can handle the string-to-light part of the code, but am very unfamiliar with the wireless portion. Once I upload the script with the wireless "credentials" onto the Arduino, I would like it to just run whenever there's power/ the credentials change!

Sorry for the long mess, I know the question is a little buried and that there are similar questions, but I'm hoping by providing all the info, somebody might point me to a similar project, or have some advice with the whole project in context.

-Alex

Comment: a quick google search results in this .... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101

Comment: most reliable is Ethernet by cable, not WiFi